# Trouble reading a number from a file and assigning it to an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

As title states, I'm trying to read numbers from an external text file and assign them to an array. I'm able to manipulate the array and write the result to another file if I manually create the array, but as is, the `fscanf()` is pulling garbage from the text file. This is what I currently have, I've been reading other posts here and I've changed it like 12 times now but I think I'm getting farther from the solution.

```
filename = argv[1];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("\n     Unable to open input file.\n\n");
        helpmssg();
        exitmssg();
}
while (getc(fp) != EOF){
        if (fscanf(fp,"%d", &c) == 1) {
                arr[i] = c;
                i++;
        }
}
```

Ideally this should scan the file specified as a command line argument for a number, assign it to the first spot of the array, and repeat until the end of file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Text file:

```
12
23
99
66
47
2
-111
8
```

Per request adding whole main function:

```
void main(int argc,char** argv) {
char* filename;
char* outputfile;
char conf;
int arr[1000] = {0};
int n,a=0,d=0,h=0,i=0,c=0;
welcome();
        if (argc > 4 || argc < 3) {
                printf("\n     Invalid number of arguments.\n\n");
                helpmssg();
                exitmssg();
        }
        else if (argc == 4) {
                for (int i=3;i<argc;i++) {
                        if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
                                for(int z=1;z<strlen(argv[i]);z++) {
                                        if (argv[i][z] == 'a') {
                                                a=1;
                                        }
                                        else if (argv[i][z] == 'd') {
                                                d=1;
                                        }
                                        else if (argv[i][z] == 'h') {
                                                h=1;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                                        printf("\n     Invalid options in 3rd argument.\n\n");
                                                        helpmssg();
                                                        exitmssg();
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                                printf("\n     3rd argument shoule begin with '-'\n\n");
                                helpmssg();
                                exitmssg();
                        }
        }       }
        filename = argv[1];
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("\n     Unable to open input file.\n\n");
                helpmssg();
                exitmssg();
        }
  while ((c=getc(fp)) != EOF){
                ungetc (c,fp);
                if (fscanf(fp,"%d\n", &c) == 1) {
                        arr[i] = c;
                        i++;n++;
                }
        }

//      int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90};
        sort(arr, n,d);
        printf("Sorted array: \n");
        printArray(arr, n);

        outputfile = argv[2];
        fp = fopen(outputfile, "r");
                if (fp != NULL ) {
                        printf("\n     Output file already exists, would you like to overwrite it?: Y/N  \n\n");
                        scanf("%c", &conf);
                                if (conf == 'N' || conf == 'n') {
                                        helpmssg();
                                        exitmssg();
                                } else {printf("     Overwritting...\n\n");}
                }
        fclose(fp);
        fp = fopen(outputfile, "w");
                for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
                        fprintf(fp,"%d\n",arr[i]);
                }
        exitmssg();
}
```

Comment: Should not code consider the result of `getc(fp)` might be part of a `int`?  (first very digit or signed after a number)?  How about `i` too big?

Comment: It probably doesn't help that you're reading a character with `getc(fp)`, in the while loop condition (thereby incrementing the file position by one), then reading the rest of the line with `fscanf`.

Comment: I know.. It's a mess. I grabbed that off another post here hoping it would accomplish what i'm looking for, but it isn't. I need to limit the input to just the numbers from the text file. I've updated the ask with the current output.

Comment: Can you post the input file as well?

Comment: Yup, should be updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `while (getc(fp) != EOF)` to `while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)`.

Add `ungetc (c, fp);` below it in the loop and before the if statement.

Change `if (fscanf(fp,"%d", &c) == 1) {` to `if (fscanf(fp,"%d\n", &c) == 1) {`

Comment: Does ungetc need to be initialized in some way? I currently have:        `while ((c=getc(fp)) != EOF){
                unget (c,fp);
                if (fscanf(fp,"%d\n", &c) == 1) {
                        arr[i] = c;
                        i++;
                }
        }
`
But i'm getting an implicit initialization warning and undefined reference to ungetc error.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just puts the character `c` back into the file stream `fp`. It becomes the next character read  when library functions read from it. Note that it does not put that character back into the file.

Comment: I'm dumb, I had unget rather than ungetc. Now it compiles. This solution is also grabbing a 0 and 194 from somewhere. Any idea why it's also grabbing those numbers? could it be the null terminator or new line or something? Thanks for all your help with this!

Comment: Can you post where `i` and `arr` are declared and initialized (is `i` initialized to 0, or at all?), and the code where you output `arr`?  Better yet, just copy-paste your whole main function--the updated version of course--and any functions you have that do I/O.

Comment: I've updated to show all of main, and in the process I think I've fixed it. Adding n++ to the inner loop of the file reading gets an accurate count of the array we've created and limited the output I was sending to the write file. I've also initialized the starting value of the array to all zero's to be on the safe side.
i just want to thank you so much for spending time helping me with this problem. This community is always so helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
for(i=0; i<size ; ++i)
{
    if( fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i])!=1 )
    {
        printf("\nSomething went wrong.");
        break;
    }
}
```

where `size` is the number of numbers stored in the array.

Use `fscanf()` to read the integers in each line one by one. It returns the number of successful assignments which in this case should be `1` in each iteration of the loop.

In your program, you first use `getc()`, which reads one character, and then use `fscanf()` which reads only the rest.

Comment: This way is looking very promising! Thank you, however I am getting an output of:
`-111 0 2 8 12 23 47 66 99 194` Somehow it also pulled a 0 and 194 from somewhere. Any ideas?